# Is it possible to Post Data from a Java application to a .php page?

Tags: java, php

im trying to make a quick java app that posts data to a website just basic $_POST variables.
Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it is.  What is your question?

Comment: possible there are several ways do it depending on what you like

Comment: Have you tried anything? I think if you google for "java http post" you get some good tutorials to get you started. -1 because it doesn't seem like you've tried anything.

Answer (score 2):

it's working like this for exmaple

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

try {

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();                
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://some.server.com/script.php");
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("var1", "value1"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("var2", "value2"));
    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
    InputStream result = response.getEntity().getContent(); 

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

} catch (IOException e) {

}
```