# how to send my application's database to a server in android

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I'm using my application on android as a client with an ASP.NET server. I have already got an SQLite library for the server and I can process SQLite files there. The database files i got until now were from using the emulator's files (manually)

I just want to access my database file from the application, and send it to the server. The database is for the same application, so I would think that it is doable, I just have no idea how to try it

Comment: not really now, I was searching for a way to start but couldn't find. I forgot to mention that I'm new to android programming... i have other programming background though. I'm still searching at the moment. I will let you know if i found anything,,, basically, I just need to grab the database file, my friend knows how to send any file type to a server

Comment: The database file resides in `/data/data/com.yourdomain.yourapp/databases/`, you can just read the raw bytes of the file and transfer them to the server.

Comment: so I've tried this, i think it worked:
try {
   File f = new File("/data/data/himura.test.dbtrail/databases/DataBase");
  } catch (Exception e) {
   Log.i("Check", "didn't work out");
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
        Log.i("Check", "maybe worked!");

Comment: Thank you @Neevek. It turned out to be so simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this could also work for android: http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/HTTP_Post_multipart_file_upload_in_Java_ME

Answer (score 0):

Use post requests to send the data to the server. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10256822/is-it-possible-to-post-data-from-a-java-application-to-a-php-page/10256854#10256854). You can read all your data from the client's database for exmaple into an XML string, send it to the server in a single post variable and read it on the server to store it in the server'S database.

Comment: Yes I have that option only if I cannot grab the database file itself. My question is solely based on me grabbing the database file, is it doable? Thank you for the link :)